# RoboVM: Error running robovm project

Tags: libgdx, llvm-clang, robovm

My target is to port libgdx game to iOS.
I have followed intallation instruction from http://www.robovm.org/docs.html

clang and robovm is installed according to the instruction.

From eclipse with robovm plugin installed, if i run for iOS simulator app following error message is shown. Same for converting a single java class file from terminal.

```
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [ INFO] Building executable
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] Compiling java.lang.Byte
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] Optimizing java.lang.Byte
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] /opt/llvm/bin/opt -mem2reg -always-inline -o=/Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.bc /Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.ll
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] Generating x86 assembly for java.lang.Byte
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] /opt/llvm/bin/llc -mtriple=i386-unknown-ios -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -disable-fp-elim -o=/Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.s /Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.bc
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] Assembling java.lang.Byte
7/9/13 12:31:13 PM: [DEBUG] /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -c -o /Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.o -g -arch i386 /Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.s
7/9/13 12:31:14 PM: [ERROR] /Users/pgs/.robovm/cache/ios/x86/default/opt/robovm-0.0.2/lib/robovm-rt.jar/java/lang/Byte.class.s:474:2: error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'vcvtsi2ssl'
7/9/13 12:31:14 PM: [ERROR]  vcvtsi2ssl %eax, %xmm0, %xmm0
7/9/13 12:31:14 PM: [ERROR]  ^~~~~~~~~~
7/9/13 12:31:14 PM: [ERROR] Build failed
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved :)

Need to use clang version: **clang+llvm-3.2-x86_64-apple-darwin11**

I was using version:clang+llvm-3.3-x86_64-apple-darwin12 earlier.